# Filter predicate function not returning anything for the first time MatTableDataSource angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

The below function is not working for the first time when we enter the first letter in the search bar and it returns nothing in the array and later when we remove the letter and continue typing, it is working fine.

```
 customFilterPredicate() {
    this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
     let myFilterPredicate = function (data: LabelElement, filter: string) : boolean{
      let searchString = JSON.parse(filter);
      return data.referenceNumber.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.referenceNumber.toLowerCase()) !== -1 && data.referenceNumberDetails.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.Href.toLowerCase()) !== -1;//|| data.referenceNumberDetails.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchString.Href);
    }

    return myFilterPredicate;
  }
```

Actually, when I debug, I see that it is entering the function and reach till the first line `this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);`
After that it is not going into the `myFilterPredicate` function and returns nothing.

The complete code is below:

```
addReferenceFilter(){
    this.refFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((refFiltervalue) => {
      this.filteredValues['referenceNumber'] = refFiltervalue;
      this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.customFilterPredicate();
      if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
        this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
      }
    });

  }

  customFilterPredicate() {
    this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
     let myFilterPredicate = function (data: LabelElement, filter: string) : boolean{
      let searchString = JSON.parse(filter);
      return data.referenceNumber.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.referenceNumber.toLowerCase()) !== -1 && data.referenceNumberDetails.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.Href.toLowerCase()) !== -1;//|| data.referenceNumberDetails.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchString.Href);
    }

    return myFilterPredicate;
  }

  addHrefFilter(){
    this.hrefFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((hrefFiltervalue) => {
      this.filteredValues['Href'] = hrefFiltervalue;
      //this.dataSource.filter = hrefFiltervalue.trim().toLowerCase();
      this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.customFilterPredicate();
      if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
        this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
      }
    });

  }

ngOnInit(){
 this.addReferenceFilter();
    this.addHrefFilter();
}
```

> Component.html

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

          <!-- Checkbox Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="select-width">Select
              <div>
                <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle($event) : null" [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()" [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
                  [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
                </mat-checkbox>
              </div>
            </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
              <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null" [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
                [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
              </mat-checkbox>
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <!-- referenceNumber Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="referenceNumber">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="select-reference"> Reference Number
              <mat-form-field class="filter-class">
                <input matInput [formControl]="refFilter">
                <mat-icon>
                  <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </mat-icon>
              </mat-form-field>
            </th>
            <!-- *ngIf="findInArr(element.referenceNumberDetails) || href.length==0" -->
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><span >{{element.referenceNumber}}</span> </td>
          </ng-container>
          <!--href-->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="Href">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="select-tracking"> Href 
              <mat-form-field class="filter-class">
                <input matInput [formControl]="hrefFilter" [(ngModel)]="href">
                <mat-icon>
                  <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </mat-icon>
              </mat-form-field>
            </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              <div *ngFor="let trackingNo of element.referenceNumberDetails"><span *ngIf="trackingNo[0].includes(href) || href.length ==0">{{trackingNo[0]}}</span></div>
            </td>
          </ng-container>
          <!-- trackingNumbers Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="trackingNumber">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="select-tracking"> Tracking Number(s) </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              <div *ngFor="let trackingNo of element.referenceNumberDetails"><span *ngIf="trackingNo[0].includes(href) || href.length ==0">{{trackingNo[1]}}</span></div>
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns;   sticky: true"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="selection.toggle(row)">

          </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: please share component.html as well or stackblitz to replicate this issue

Comment: I have updated with template file @NagaSaiA